# DSE search: how to find a row where a column whic is part of Search-index doesn’t have any value

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, solr-query-syntax, solr-search, dse

I have a SOLR search index on one of my Cassandra table.

To depict the problem here is a hypothetical table and query.
"*Please pardon me for bad design, this is just hypothetical table, concentrating on describing the problem I’m facing*”
Lets assume this is the table

```
my_keyspace.cust_items(
  cust_name   text,
  order_date  date,
  oder_id     uuid,  
  item_id     uuid,
  item_name   text,  
  item_desc   text
  item_props  map<text,text>,
primary key((cust_name),order_date,order_id, item_id));
```

I’m using `DSE (datastax enterprise) 6.x`.  So to query the data I’m leveraging `DSE SEARCH` For the sake of simplicity, lets assume all the calumn in above table are part of SOLR index.

```
CREATE SEARCH INDEX ON my_keyspace.cust_items;
```

So now when I want to find an item with name as `ITM1` for a customer named `CUST1` between date1 & date2, I use following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_keyspace.cust_items
WHERE solr_query = ‘{“q": “cust_name:CUST1 && item_name:ITM1  
&& order_date:[date1 TO date2]”}'
```

Until here, everything works great.

**What I’m unable to do.**.
for a given customer, date-range and order-id,I want to find Items, which don’t have a specific item property.
I store these properties under a map type column `item_props`.
So in this case lets say I want to fetch the items where  `item_props_prop1` has no value,
below CQL should return data but it doesn’t.

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_keyspace.cust_items
WHERE solr_query = ‘{“q": “cust_name:CUST1 && order_id:123 
&& item_props_prop1:'' && order_date:[date1 TO date2]”}'
```

All rows have key `item_props_prop1` in `item_props` map column, but in DS Studio even when the value is shown “” the above query doesn’t fetch the data.

Comment: A document missing a field can be retrieved by querying for `*:* -field:[* TO *]`, and empty field can be queried for as `field:""` - combine both with `OR` to get both: `q=(*:* -field:[* TO *]) OR field:""`; is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Actually field was not missing, it has empty values, and I did try `field:’’` using single quotes not double quotes, because of solr_query json.  but cql does not return ANY data. I updated the question to contain more info

Comment: Have you tried querying Solr directly if that's possible with datastax, instead of going through cql? I'm also not sure if single quotes gets parsed identically as double quotes in this case, so maybe escaping the quotes is a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, make sense, but as a develper, dont have that much control on repository.  I finally decided to add a value (NA) for showing the absence of property, so now I can qury for quality, instead of inequality.  but that doesn’t work for existing data, so for now we will say the feature is implemented for newer transactions only :)

Comment: If you have well-defined values in the field (i.e. you know what the lowest, first character is), you can try making a range query - for example `field:[a TO *]` should match all fields with at least some text - you can replace `a` with `0` as well if you have numeric string values). So you end up with `*:* -field:[a TO *]` as your query (i.e. all documents, except those that have a value that's at least ordered from `a` and up)